# Can't close temporary files made with the Python tempfile module

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am using an ffmpeg based module called `pydub` to edit an audio file. I am trying to use the module `tempfile`, but for some reason I can't close the files (they arent deleted). When using a context manager it throws a `PermissionError`.

**What I tried:**

This code works like intended, however it does not delete the tempfile(s), no error is thrown.

```py
temp1, temp2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='data/temp', delete=False), None
# save something to temp1
seg = AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(temp1)

if options['overlay']:
    # create new seg
    if overlay_seg:
        temp2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='data/temp', delete=False)
        # save something to temp2
        overlay_seg = AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(temp2)
        seg = seg.overlay(overlay_seg)

# edit the audio more here..

final = 'data//temp//edited.mp3'
seg.export(final, bitrate=options['bitrate'], format='mp3')
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(final)) # sends the file to a Discord chat
temp1.close()
if temp2:
    temp2.close()
```

This creates the first temp file, then it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<myfile>", line 153, in editaudio
    await attachment.save(temp1.name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 155, in save
    with open(fp, 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<base>data\\temp\\tmpnf2r68qe'
```

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='data/temp') as temp1: 
    await attachment.save(temp1.name)
    seg = AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(temp1)
    if options['overlay']:
        # create new seg
        if overlay_seg:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='data/temp') as temp2:
                # save something to temp2
                overlay_seg = AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(temp2)
                seg = seg.overlay(overlay_seg)

    # edit the audio more here..

    final = 'data//temp//edited.mp3'
    seg.export(final, bitrate=options['bitrate'], format='mp3')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(final)) # sends the file to a Discord chat
```

I am not sure what I am missing here

Comment: To actually delete the file I apparently had to `os.unlink(temp.name)` as well as temp.close(), I still don't understand why it throws a Permissionerror when using the context manager though.

Comment: Does `await attachment.save(f1)` work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your tempfiles do not get deleted if you create them with the option `delete=False`. This is self explanatory but also mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile).

Your second approach is hard to debug since you do not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Presumably the problem arises because you already opened the tempfile by using the context manager. `attachment.save()` probably expects a path, but I couldn't find a documentation online.